# Correct writing of the php code and html - PHP

Tags: php, html

I do not know how to call this situation in technical ranks, I will post two fully functional codes, my goal is to be able to write my code in a more "easy" for me.

In the code that I will post below I'm initializing a while loop but this form of writing gives me the possibility of not losing boring time between single quotes essential for php echos because I have the possibility to insert free html code in order to build more easily the frontend part

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE';

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$query_string = "QUERY";

$query = mysqli_query($VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE, $query_string);

?>



<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

HTML   <?php echo $row['NOME_CAMPO_TABELLA'] ;?>   HTML

<?php } ?>
```

and here we come to the heart of the matter, I have this other piece of code but I've tried to smash my head a bit but without any result I would like to have the possibility to write the code as above in order to write faster the html part

```
<?php
//fetch.php
include '../../../connessione.php';
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $cerca = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE nome_cliente LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR cognome_cliente LIKE '%".$cerca."%' 
  OR azienda_cliente LIKE '%".$cerca."%' 
  OR telefono_cliente LIKE '%".$cerca."%' 
  OR email_cliente LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
 ";

}
else
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id_cliente";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connessione, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Customer Name</th>
     <th>cognome_cliente</th>
     <th>azienda_cliente</th>
     <th>Postal Code</th>
     <th>email_cliente</th>
    </tr>
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["nome_cliente"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["cognome_cliente"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["azienda_cliente"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["telefono_cliente"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["email_cliente"].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Nessun risultato corrisponde alla tua ricerca';
}

?>
```

Comment: You want the html part out of the php tag right?

Comment: yes i want this

Comment: For the like I'd just use `concat` on all the columns and through a space in between them. It will function the same and you'll only need the variable once. e.g. `SELECT * FROM ca2_2ac_clienti WHERE concat(nome_cliente, ' ', cognome_cliente, ' ', azienda_cliente, ' ', telefono_cliente, ' ',  email_cliente) LIKE '%".$cerca."%`

Comment: guys you're all very kind but if you were just as kind to write me the code because I really do not know how it can be performed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code below:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
?>
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Customer Name</th>
     <th>cognome_cliente</th>
     <th>azienda_cliente</th>
     <th>Postal Code</th>
     <th>email_cliente</th>
    </tr>
<?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["nome_cliente"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["cognome_cliente"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["azienda_cliente"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["nome_cliente"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["email_cliente"]; ?></td>
   </tr>
  <?php
 }
```

Comment: is there any error? i didn't run it, just wrote it on the go.

Comment: Oh i got it sorry

Comment: if you are so kind to put me from top to bottom the code because surely I will be wrong to implement your code in my

Comment: I edited the code check this one, this is so simple just close the `php` with `?>` when ever you want to start writing `HTML` and remember u can't use `php` variables [as i first did inside your] `HTML`, then open `php` tag whenever you want to use `php` variables or start writing `php` again...

Comment: Not to mention i just edited part of your code so just replace those lines

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0NyxX8CY this is how I wrote it but it does not work

Comment: Upvote for the edits. Thx for not leaving it like it was

Comment: MamaLord 
if you read this comment you could kindly send me again the link to pastebin because the current is skipped and my pc has not saved anything